# Can I have different services running different languages in the same Google App Engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Google App Engine allows you to deploy multiple different services that (afaik) sit in different containers. Is it possible to have one of my services running in a, say, Java container; and a second service running in, say, a NodeJS container? Or must all my containers for all my services be the same language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Code can be deployed to services independently, and different services can be written in different languages, such as Python, Java, Go, and PHP

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine